# Getting existing file handle windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to use [SetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) function to set creation, modification and last access time to times from another file.

Do you know how can I get a file handle of an existing file? I want to iterate over all the files in a directory using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`, but it doesn't give me the handles to all the files, just to the first one.

Comment: FindFirstFile and FindNextFile don't give you any file handles at all

Comment: @0123456789 What if I want to use it with already existing file?

Comment: SetFileTime: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx
"The handle must have been created using the CreateFile function with the FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES access right."
CreateFile: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx
"Creates or opens a file or I/O device."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handle for `SetFileTime` must be obtained by opening the file with [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

The handle returned by `FindFirstFile` can be used exclusively for subsequent calls to `FindNextFile` and to `FindClose`.

Comment: But cannot I change those values for an existing file?

Comment: @Fulaphex `CreateFile` is used to both create new files, and open existing files. It is the way to obtain a handle to a file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I figured out how to do it, thanks for the tips.